# WCF FaultException<T> is not caught in client, instead caught as service fault

Tags: wcf, exception, faultexception

I have service configured for FaultException but on the client end I am not getting the exception caught in

```
catch (FaultException<MyServiceFault> fe)
{
}
```

instead it is always caught in

```
catch (FaultException fx) 
{ 
}
```

I am using selfhost and channelfactory.

my Service:

```
[FaultContract(typeof(MyServiceFault))]
public string HelloWorld()
{
    int a=5;
    try
    {
        var b = a/0;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw new FaultException<MyServiceFault>(new MyServiceFault(){Message ="Divide by zero"}, "Divide by Zero");
    }
}
```

I also have the `[DataContract]` attribute on the `MyServiceFault`.
I am wondering if I miss any configuration.

Comment: This all looks correct to me; can you include the details of the faultexception you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

I've answered a similar question here: [Proper way to throw exception over WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138277/proper-way-to-throw-exception-over-wcf)

Try to declare your operation like this:

```
[FaultContractAttribute(
        typeof(MyServiceFault),
        Action = "", 
        Name = "MyServiceFault", 
        Namespace = "YourNamespace")]
public string HelloWorld()
```

Hope it helps.