# No signature message parts were specified for messages

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a two WCF services,one is calling another one.I am using these methods for validating users. This is my first service method

```
 [OperationContract]
        [FaultContract(typeof(MyNawrasWCFException))]
        bool ValidateUser(string username);
```

and internally it is calling another service method like this(its not calling it directly,but is calling through an adapter)

```
 ServiceClient2 client = new ServiceClient2();
                client.Open();
                isValidated = client.ValidateUser(username);
                client.Close();
```

and in Service2 I have method like this

```
[OperationContract]
        [FaultContract(typeof(bool))]
        bool  ValidateUser(string username);
```

This is working fine on my local machine,but when I deployed it on server,its

```
showing error
No signature message parts were specified for messages with the 'http://tempuri.org/IService2/ValidateUserExceptionFault' action.
```

I have read on google to fix this error,I need to update the service reference. I have updated the reference but still same error. I have other methods too but its showing error only  in this method

Comment: Probably is the way you created your custom exception class.
Take a look in this post that I gave an example on how to do it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138277/proper-way-to-throw-exception-over-wcf
Let me know if helped