# Exception unhandled by user code C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have WCF service in which I want raise an Exception, when I am raising an exception then I getting Error **Exception unhandled by user code**. Please someone can figure this Issue. My Interface is as follows:

```
 [ServiceContract]
 public interface IADSICAuthentication
 {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Login", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [OperationContract]
        Response LoginClient(Credentials credentials);
}
```

and my LoginCLient Method defines below

```
public Response LoginClient(Credentials oCredentials)
 {
   try
   {
    if(oCredentials.PassWord == null)
    {
        //something
    }
    else
    {
      throw new Exception(string.Format("UnAuthorize User : 401"));
    }
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      throw; // I am getting Exception here Unhandled by user code
   }


}
```

Comment: if you are throwing then why catching again, and again throwing the same?

Comment: Did you debug it? Can "oCredentials" be null?

Answer (score 1):

You can use FaultException. FaultException can throw a specific exception, so you will be able to identify the type using catch.

Here I gave an similar answer with an example: [Proper way to throw exception over WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138277/proper-way-to-throw-exception-over-wcf/31145089#31145089)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `FaultException<T>` and mark up your `ServiceContract` class to include which types are expected.

Details on how to use it are available at [MSDN - FaultException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576199(v=vs.110).aspx)